# Standard practice to FTP and send a file over email in unix

Tags: shell, unix, cron

We have a requirement wherein we need to read data from database, create a CSV file based on it, ftp that file and mail it to certain list.

Just wanted to know what would be the standard practice to do that?

I mean how to use cron job, Shell script, stored procedure, etc.

We are using oracle db, Unix server.

TIA...

Comment: a programming language maybe? like python...

Comment: Can it be done without any external programming language?? I mean shell script directly calling stored proc for creating file and then ftp and mail it using shell script?

Comment: (separately) You'll find many questions here on S.O. with good answers about a. getting a file from a database, b. others about ftp files, and c. still others about emailing msgs to lists, all you have to do is "glue" the solutions together. Its a little unusual to both `ftp` AND `email` files to different "targets", but not difficult at all in shell scripting. Fancy formatting on emails will be a separate project. Good luck.